# c++ application crashes when no args are entered

Tags: c++, arguments

I am creating a command line based encryption software. I have an if statement here, to check if there is no arguments, and exit with code 1.

```
if (argc = 0) {
    errorExit("No arguments listed. Type \"-h\" for help.", 1);
}
```

errorExit() is in a header file I created.

```
int errorExit(string errMsg, int errorCode) {
cerr << "Error: ";
cerr << errMsg;
cerr << endl;
exit(errorCode);
return NULL;
```

}

My program instead crashes when I type in no arguments.

```
Z:\Code\C++\CodeBlocks\simplecrypt\bin\Debug>simplecrypt.exe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
   what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Z:\Code\C++\CodeBlocks\simplecrypt\bin\Debug>
```

To clear up confusion I am using codeblocks with mingw, in case its a bug in mingw.

EDIT: I realized that I have argc = 0 instead of argc == 0. I realized the error but still didnt fix the problem.

Comment: For start I'd be good you change "if (argc = 0)"  to "==" comparison operator

Comment: You most likely want to return `0` and not `NULL`.  Although it generally means the same thing, mixing `int` and `NULL` just confuses people.  It would be nice to see a complete example.

Comment: Anyone who defines `NULL` as anything other than a bare `0` is a thorn in the side of humanity.

Comment: You need to post more relevant code because `argc` on most systems is  _at least_ 1 (`argv[0]` == program name) .. so that code never gets run, additionally, even it did run, there's nothing in the code you posted to indicate that `basic_string::_S_construct null not valid` exception should be thrown.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5015c61610cd3e1).  Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The main function may be declared like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]);
```

When you call the program in command line, the argv[0] would be the name of executable, which means the argc should be 1 if there is no other arguments.

Comment: so, the argc will never be 0?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(argc == 0){...
```

Write == and not = in the if condiction